# Vue.js get element's html value by clicking on it's neighboring element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Hello everyone I'm building a simple notes app and I can't figure out how to implement one feature.

I have a card element and delete button as a child of this element. I need to check if the card element child's(.card-title) html value(jQuery's .html()) is equal to the localStorage(I'm using for to loop through the localStorage object) key by clicking on Delete button(that is a child of the card element alongside with the card's title) .Then, if true, I need to delete the localStorage item by key that is equal to the .card-title's html value.

So basically I have

- .card

  - .card-title (with html value I need to get)
  - .card-body (nothing to do with it)
  - .delete-button (by clicking on it I need to get .card-title's html value)

That's only my point of view, which, most likely, is wrong. So, maybe, there is a better approach for deleting notes in my app?

Any ideas?

[Full code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/YegorGunko/pen/vdBjvB?editors=1010)

Thank you very much for spending your precious time with my issue! Thank you for any help!

So I have a code like this :

```html
<div id="notes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Enter title</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="title"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Enter body</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="add">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="clear">Delete all</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" v-for="o,t,b,c in notes">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{t}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{o[b]}}</p>
        <a class="card-link" @click="remove">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#notes",
    data: {
        notes: {}
    },
    methods: {
        add: function() {
            localStorage.setItem($("#title").val(), $("#body").val());
            location.reload(true);
        },
        clear: function() {
            localStorage.clear();
            location.reload(true);
        },
        remove: function(e) {
            for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                if (
                    localStorage.key(i) ==
                    $(this)
                    .closest(".card")
                    .find(".card-title")
                    .html()
                ) {
                    alert(true);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            this.notes[localStorage.key(i)] = [
                localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)),
                "red"
            ];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i built this very simple app so you can check it out
https://jsfiddle.net/vrxonsq1/2/

```
new Vue({
el:"#app",
data:{
form:{
    title:"",
    body:""
},
notes:[]
},
methods:{
add: function(){
    this.notes.push({
    title: this.form.title,
    body: this.form.body
  });
  this.form.title = "";
  this.form.body = "";
  this.save();
},
remove: function(title){
        this.notes.forEach(function(note,index){
    if (note.title == title){
        this.notes.splice(index,1);
    }
  })
  this.save();
},
save: function(){
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(this.notes) );
}
},
created: function(){
notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes") );
this.notes = notes ? notes : []  
}
})
```

it doesn't use jquery, only vuejs, I think it is better this way

simply create an array contains 'note' objects where each one have title and body.

Tell me if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since it's already late in my country, I'll look into it tomorrow, thanks again :)

Comment: Well, what does this.save() does and how it works? Can you please explain?

Comment: it calls the "save" method which stores the notes in localStorage. I extracted to its own method because I used it twice, in add and remove methods, so I don't have to repeat the code twice and becomes easy to manage

Comment: Well, yeah, this makes sense, sorry, I'm very new to Vue so it's a bit complicated for me to understand everything, but I think I can figure so functions out

Comment: Still hard to realise how to data from the <input>s are gathered

Comment: I am using [form input binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) with the v-model attribute to bind the value of the model to the form object in vue data

Comment: think I gonna dig into it tomorrow, since I'm already sleepy today, thanks a lot again :3

Comment: thank you very much, also, I have a Telegram account, I would be glad if I can have a contact with you :) my id is : YegorGunko

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can get an elements parent element with .parent().
So in this case you should be able to do this to get the html you're looking for:

```
$(this).parent().find('.card-title').html()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well, I think that the problem is with my function for removing items so this doesn't work and I have no clue how to fix it. If it's possible for you to look through my code on CodePen : https://codepen.io/YegorGunko/pen/vdBjvB?editors=1010

Comment: You shouldn't mix jQuery with something like Vue because it is data driven. The data should dictate how the DOM looks and the data is also your point of reference. Therefore you shouldn't check the DOM to compare elements when you have the data present already. It is bad practice and something you want to avoid since you no longer have a single source of truth when you start doing this.

Comment: @Stephan-v Well, I'm new to Vue so I just need to understand how to use _this_ with Vue functions and **v-on:click=""** I know that jQuery is a bad approach to use with Vue, but I use it just for understanding Vue(since jQuery is handy for me and I can understand it a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the solution myself, thanks everyone for help!

Updated code :

```
new Vue({
    el: "#notes",
    data: {
        notes: {}
    },
    methods: {
        add: function() {
            localStorage.setItem($("#title").val(), $("#body").val());
            location.reload(true);
        },
        clear: function() {
            localStorage.clear();
            location.reload(true);
        },
        remove: function(e) {
            var t = $(e.target)
                .parent()
                .find(".card-title")
                .html();
            for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                if (localStorage.key(i) == t) {
                    localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(t));
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            this.notes[localStorage.key(i)] = [
                localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)),
                "red"
            ];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to use VueJS' [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

Assigning a ref to your elements gives you access to the specifically named DOM element within your component via a `$refs` property on `this` e.g

```
<div ref="myDiv">I'm a div</div> // = { myDiv: [DOMELEMENT] }

created () { 
  console.log(this.$refs.myDiv.innerHTML) // I'm a div
}
```

By using refs you should be able to use `querySelector` to query child elements of parent elements and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Well, it seems like ref doesn't work inside of the element that is nested inside v-for, am I wrong?

Comment: You'd have to be smart in the way that you declare your `refs` - if you create your ref based on a property of your object in the loop and also pass it to your remove function - you could dynamically access your refs based on that argument e.g `(refFromLoop) => console.log(this.$refs[refFromLoop])`